# Mathjax ignore latex on the page

Tags: javascript, latex, mathjax

Can I make Mathjax to not render the latex on the page inmediately?

I could remove all the `$` symbols on the html and later on add them and call the typeset function `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub])`, but I'm asking if there's a better way to delay Mathjax from rendering the latex on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this code that does the thing:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
       skipStartupTypeset: true
    });
</script>
```